# Are partitions on different Kafka topics co-located within same consumer (k8s pod)

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a requirement where I want to be able to read data from partition 1 of topic A and partition 1 of topic B from the same consumer, I have a group of consumers running in different Kubernetes pods. Both topics will have 5 partitions each and both topics have key based partition strategy.

So assuming partition 1 on topic A and partition 1 on topic B are keyed with same key value would they both colocate on the same consumer or pod? If that's the case then I can cross reference data from one topic using the key of the other topic's message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys are only relevant to the producer partitioner.

There is no guarantee that a consumer will be assigned the same partitions across two topics. The `ConsumerPartitionAssignor` linked below is only per-topic. You might get lucky with consumers assigned partitions with the same keys across topics, but after a rebalancing, it'll no longer be true.

If you must consume the same partition of multiple topics, you may `assign()` those values to the consumer instance rather than `subscribe()`-ing to the whole topic.

However, if you are wanting to join data across topics, the more appropriate way to do this would be to use Kafka Streams / KSQL joins.

Comment: Is this the case even if there are same number of partitions on both topics being consumed? I.e co-located partitions won't be possible even then? If it is possible then ```assign()``` is what should be used and not ```subscribe()```?

Yes we are looking to go the Kstreams way in future but for now it's not possible.

Comment: @Tabber Kafka consumer subscribe method doesn't provide such a feature, no. If you want to override this behavior, use an assignor https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerPartitionAssignor.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you configure routing by key for both topics, same key will be sent to same partition. Have a look at the documentation here : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_loadbalancing

"For example if the key chosen was a user id then all data for a given user would be sent to the same partition. This in turn will allow consumers to make locality assumptions about their consumption. This style of partitioning is explicitly designed to allow locality-sensitive processing in consumers."

Comment: The question is asking about consumers, not producers

Comment: Producers need to route messages correctly into partitions so that consumers can consume colocated messages. If producers send same key to same partition, consumers know that by consuming the same partition of both topics, they'll have the same keys.

Comment: 1) That's assuming both topics have the same number of partitions and the same partitioner is used by the producer 2) OP is asking if keys have any relevance to the consumer assignment of multiple topics, which they don't

Comment: 1) OP indicates that there will be 5 partitions in topic A and topic B.
2) OP indicates that its consumer will be assigned to partition 1 of topic A and parition 1 of topic B.
Then if keys are hashed the same way in both topic, a consumer will receive the same keys from both topics.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is it's asking **if** the consumer will be assigned the same partitions of any topic since the keys are the same, not that they **will be**. The answer to that is a no. Still your answer here only addresses producer behavior.